# Magento1.9 - How to rewrite exact url using xml

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I want to rewrite `/custom` link from `/catalogsearch/result/?q=some&attr=value` for this I have added below code in my module config.xml

```
...
<rewrite>
    <mymodule>
        <from><![CDATA[/custom/]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[catalogsearch/result/index/q/some/attr/value/$1]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </mymodule>
</rewrite>
...
```

From above code url `/custom` showing content of search page, but the other url including `custom` also rewritten from above code. for example `/custom-page` or `custom-page1`.

How to rewrite exact url?

Answer (score 1):

To override the Catalog Search controller,

I request you to use below method instead of old frontend:

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
       <catalogsearch>
          <args>
            <modules>
              <yournamespace_module before="Mage_CatalogSearch">Yournamespace_Module</yournamespace_module>
            </modules>
          </args>
       </catalogsearch>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

It will redirect every request with your custom one.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Please check my question first I don't want to overwrite controller or don't want to change any functionality, I have a cms page "/custom" and want to get same content from the mentioned url on my page.

Comment: if it is CMS page so you can call catalog search blocks in layout xml updates

Comment: please post regarding xml.